# In Rails, how do I convert and print a time to a different time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I have a variable, start_time:

```
(rdb:5) start_time.class
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

(rdb:5) start_time
Tue, 23 Feb 2010 14:45:00 EST -05:00

(rdb:5) start_time.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::ZONES_MAP["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]).zone
"PST"

(rdb:5) start_time.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone::ZONES_MAP["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]).to_s(:time)
"2:45 PM ET"
```

I'd like to change 'to_s(:time)' so that it outputs the time in whatever zone is specified in the variable, not the default system time.  I.e. The output would be "11:45 AM PT".  How do I do this?

Comment: Touche.  I should do something about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently and was able to solve it by essentially overriding the `.to_s` option that I was using. I created an initializer called time_formats.rb and added the following line to it.

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:time_in_zone] = "%H:%M %p"
```

then changed `(:time)` to `(:time_in_zone)` like so...

```
start_time.in_time_zone(...your timezone here...]).to_s(:time_in_zone)
```

It *should* give you the time in the zone you are specifying. My environment is in UTC, so maybe that had something to do with it...

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to create a `TimeZone` object, and use its `at()` method:

```
start_time = Time.now 
start_time.rfc822                          # => "Tue, 23 Feb 2010 10:58:23 -0500"
pst = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"]
pst.at(start_time).strftime("%H:%M %p %Z") # => "08:00 AM PST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given Beerlington's comments, I ended up adding the following (which is similar to the Proc defined for Time::DATE_FORMATS[:time]

```
:time_in_zone  => lambda { |time|
    time = time.strftime("%I:%M %p %Z").gsub(/([NAECMP])([DS])T$/, '\1T')
    time = time[1..-1] if time =~ /^0/ # drop leading zeroes
    time
}
```